# regex for finding date dir

Tags: bash

i am looking to search for  in dir ...

a2010-02-10

how to search the ls all dir in with date format

```
ls -d *(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)
```

its not working like perl

what is the right format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex appears to be correct, but bash doesn't support full regular expressions.  It supports [wildcards](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html), which can't always work the same way.  Try this:

```
ls -d | grep -E '(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$'
```

And really, the `(\d+)` groups could be replaced with just `\d+`.

If you prefer a pure-bash solution, try this:

```
ls -d *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

You can simplify that to be less exact if desired:

```
ls -d *[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*
```

But I'd go for using `grep` because it is a lot clearer what you want.  You could make it even clearer:

```
ls -d | grep -E '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `shopt -s extglob`, you can do:

```
ls -d *+([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9])
```